# Unexpected output in narcissistic number check in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I had written this code to print the narcissistic numbers under 10000 in python

```
for num in range(0,10000):
    armSum = 0
    for strNum in str(num):
        if len(str(num)) <= 3:
            for strNum in str(num):
                armSum += int(strNum)**3
            if armSum == num:
                print("Three digit Narcissistic number:",num)

        elif len(str(num)) == 4:
            for strNum in str(num):
                armSum += int(strNum)**4
            if armSum == num:
                print("Four digit Narcissistic number:",num)
```

But the output of this code prints an extra number 702, which isn't a narcissistic number.

Output:

```
Three digit Narcissistic number: 0
Three digit Narcissistic number: 1
Three digit Narcissistic number: 153
Three digit Narcissistic number: 370
Three digit Narcissistic number: 371
Three digit Narcissistic number: 407
Three digit Narcissistic number: 702
Four digit Narcissistic number: 1634
Four digit Narcissistic number: 8208
Four digit Narcissistic number: 9474
```

Where did I go wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get wrong answer is because you compute the sum twice by using the loop `for strNum in str(num):` twice.

```
>>> 2*(7**3 + 2**3 )
702
>>>
```

Also, is there any specific reason you want two if-conditions? Please see below. And giving good variable names also helps in debugging.

```
for num in range(0,10000):
    armSum = 0
    orig_num = num
    num = str(num)
    index = len(num)
    for digit in num:
        armSum += int(digit)**index
    if armSum == orig_num:
        print(f"{index} Digit Narcissistic number:",num)


user@Inspiron:~$ python nar.py 
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 0
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 1
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 2
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 3
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 4
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 5
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 6
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 7
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 8
1 Digit Narcissistic number: 9
3 Digit Narcissistic number: 153
3 Digit Narcissistic number: 370
3 Digit Narcissistic number: 371
3 Digit Narcissistic number: 407
4 Digit Narcissistic number: 1634
4 Digit Narcissistic number: 8208
4 Digit Narcissistic number: 9474
```